# Z-index not working img element hidden behind parent divs

Tags: html, css

I need to position the img element (along with other related info about the project) to the bottom right corner of the div with class 'projectItem green'.

Positioning works fine but I cannot get the img element under two parent divs to be visible on the screen. The element highlighting actually highlights the element but your can only see the grid around invisible element.

I tried to use that z-index with the img element instead of the div. I also tried to add display:block parameter to the img element and use z-index there.

Thanx a lot for any pointers!

Here is my code

```
<div class="projectItem green">
  <div class="projectNumber">I-8000</div>
  <div title="Testprojekt 25.05.2018" class="halfWidth">Testprojekt 25.05.2018</div>
  <div class="halfWidth"><span>Start:&nbsp;</span><span>5/25/2018</span></div>
  <div title="" class="halfWidth">UserName</div>
  <div class="halfWidth"><span>End:&nbsp;</span><span style="margin-left: 8px;">6/1/2020</span></div>
  <div class="halfWidth">Last status update:</div>
  <div class="halfWidth"><span style="margin-left: 43px;">5/25/2018</span></div>
  <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative; z-index: 1000;"><img style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0"
     src="/system/pscbaf/ImagesLogos/IPM/IPM_NotReported_Icon.PNG"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot from DOM

[image]

Here is what I am getting

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, can you add a working example that includes all the relevant CSS?

Comment: Hi, thanx for reply, I am new here, sorry for not including all needed info. I will put screenshots here. This will explain it better

Comment: can u add a fiddle instead of screen shots?

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve]